# Change CSS class of a <div> using dojo

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo, frontend

I would like to change the element's CSS class depending on the if statement.

This is what I have:

HTML

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="waitIcon" class="rightNode">
```

CSS

```
.rightNode{
  float: right;
  height: 75px;
  width: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.noWaitIcon{
  float: right;
  height: 75px;
  width: 60px;
  margin-top: 34px;
}
```

JS

```
if (value == 0){
     domClass.remove(this.waitIcon, "rightNode");
     domClass.add(this.waitIcon, "noWaitIcon");
else{
     domClass.remove(this.waitIcon, "noWaitIcon");
     domClass.add(this.waitIcon, "rightNode");
}
```

Comment: and what is happening ? can you provide a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data-dojo-attach-point` attribute works when you are creating a **template** based widget.

Most probably the `this` is not referring to the right object.

Anyway here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frank123/p8fb4mgs/) of dom-class which works.

```
require( [
    'dojo/dom',
    'dojo/dom-class',
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function(dom, domClass) {
    function swapColor(  ){

      if (value == 0){

        domClass.remove('node', 'red');
        domClass.add('node', 'green');
        value = 1;
      }
      else{

        domClass.remove('node', 'green');
        domClass.add('node', 'red');
        value = 0;
      }


    }
    value = 0;

    dom.byId("btn").onclick = swapColor;


});
```